# Whenever I move the camera on the left side of the screen, the cursor appears in-game. Unreal engine 5

Tags: windows, unreal-blueprint, unreal-engine5

The issue.

[image: 1]

The mouse keeps escaping the full-screen whenever I either jump, move, rotate the camera or keep spinning to the left. But only on the left side of the screen, not the right, not the middle, not beneath, only on the left side.
This has happened in other unreal engine 5 games as well, but not in every single one of them.

What I've tried so far is:

1. Disabled Set bSHowMouseCursor nodes. [No effect.]
2. Set an Event BeginPlay > Set Input Mode Game only > Get Player Controller > Set SHow Mouse Cursor (Unchecked) [No effect.]
3. Created a new template (A blank one), then packaged it for testing. [Mixed effects. It slightly reduced the rate the mouse showed on the left side of the screen.]
4. Set an Event BeginPlay > Set Input Mode Game and UI > Get Player Controller > Set SHow Mouse Cursor (Unchecked) [Mixed results - I had to hold right click in order to move the camera, in which case, the mouse stopped showing, but as soon as I released it, the left mouse not only did appear as well, but the camera could not be moved and the cursor appeared permanently on the left side of the screen.]
5. Changed both the software and hardware cursors. But the cursor is unchanged. So it's not the game's cursor that appears in-game. It's the actual windows cursor.
6. I tested every option in the Default Viewport Mouse Lock Mode.
7. Deleted both Saved and the Intermediate folders.

Someone told me it has something to do with how the mouse is locked (or not) on viewport. And that, that might be the reason behind the cursor leaving escaping full-screen.

I don't have two monitors. The game is in full-screen. The issue persists in windowed mode as well. No widgets.

Tested it in packaging and in a Standalone game. (Issue persisted.)

The issue happens only if I click the left mouse button. If I play the game without clicking it, the cursor does not appear in-game.

Update:

It appears like going to the game's exe's compatibility and changing the high DPI settings' scaling behavior to application fixes the problem but reduces the fps. This is a temporary fix but I need a permanent one.

Answer (score 0):

This is a weird issue.
What is on your left side desktop?
Do you use any apps that have an overlay?

If you have any apps try to disable them temporarily at startup from task manager, restart and check again.

---

In UE5, have you tried setting the mousecapture to true, especially in fullscreen.
Sometimes the mouse can escape...

---

Are you using a standard resolution/aspect ratio?
Some non standard resolutions and aspect ratios can change the way the base OS responds to captured/non captured input.